Как доработать систему сохранения?
Делаю систему сохранений, работает с JSON, и понадобился код для сохранения структуры. Вот наиболее нужный кусок кода для поиска проблемы:
public void SaveData(ref Data data){
data.money = this.money;
data.score = this.score;

    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
    {
        
            string id = objects[i].id;
            string content = objects[i].content;
            string nameAchivement = objects[i].nameAchivement;
            float requirement = objects[i].requirement;
            float reward = objects[i].reward;
            bool alreadyTaked = objects[i].alreadyTaken;
            AchivementClass achivement = new AchivementClass(id, nameAchivement, content, requirement, reward, alreadyTaked);
            data.achivement.Add(achivement);
    }
    data.achivement.Distinct().ToList();

Структуру записывает, но дублирует информацию, смотрел разные варианты и либо не подходит, либо не работает. Сам я пока не могу понять как сделать лучше.
В идеале надо добиться не удаления дубликатов, а сохранения точного количество элементов, возможно через банальный if
{
"money": 0.0,
"score": 0.0,
"hiscore": 0.0,
"achivement": [
    {
        "id": "",
        "nameAchivement": "Reach10coins",
        "content": "Р—Р°СЂР°Р±РѕС‚Р°Р№ 10 РјРѕРЅРµС‚",
        "requirement": 10.0,
        "reward": 20.0,
        "alreadyTaked": false
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "nameAchivement": "Reach100coins",
        "content": "Р—Р°СЂР°Р±РѕС‚Р°Р№ 100 РјРѕРЅРµС‚",
        "requirement": 200.0,
        "reward": 200.0,
        "alreadyTaked": false
    },
    {
        "id": "",
        "nameAchivement": "Reach1000coins",
        "content": "Р—Р°СЂР°Р±РѕС‚Р°Р№ 1000 РјРѕРЅРµС‚",
        "requirement": 1000.0,
        "reward": 800.0,
        "alreadyTaked": false
    }
]

Файл перезаписывает

Вы результат операции data.achivement.Distinct().ToList() никуда не записываете.

data.achivement = data.achivement.Distinct().ToList() не помог

Что значит "дублирует информацию"? Приведите больше подробностей в вопросе. У вас для AchivementClass метод сравнения перегружен? Иначе Distinct бесполезен, сравнение по дефолту только равенство ссылок проверяет, поля на равенство вы сами должны сравнивать в своём методе сравнения.

итоговую информацию в JSON он записывает при первом сохранении данных, как нужно, после повторной проверки он производит повторное сохранения, не обращая внимание на то, что эти данные уже сохранены в точности, и просто добавляет к структуре записи

Как тогда проверить? Я пытался, но не работает

Тогда у вас проблема с сохранением. Вы наверное дописываете данные в файл, а не перезаписываете его целиком. Код записи вы не привели.

файл перезаписывает, итог добавил в вопрос

Основная проблема в отсутствии проверки данных на добавление

Ладно. Попробуйте как-то переформулировать вопрос. Типа хочу вот так чтобы было (пример), а получается вот так (пример). Сейчас я не могу толком угадать, в чём ваш вопрос.

Хочу чтобы данные записывались один раз, а записывает данные которые уже есть, каждый раз при запуске кода, то есть при выходе из игры. Те же деньги или счет, он просто перезаписывает

Ну проверяйте, нет ли в списке data.achivement такого же элемента, какой вы хотите добавить.

А как мне сделать так, чтобы он проверял каждый элемент на дубликат, учитывая что некоторые данные, например bool так или иначе будут дублироваться, и можно ли сделать это как то легче?

if (achivement == data.achivement[i])
{
data.achivement.Remove(achivement);
}
else
{
data.achivement.Add(achivement);
}
Добавил такой код, не работает, все также дублирует

Ещё раз. У вас для AchivementClass описан метод сравнения?

нет, не написан

Ну так напишите. Без него не будет работать ничего, что использует сравнение (например, Distinct). И само сравнение == тоже не будет работать, если это не тот же самый прямо объект с той же ссылкой. https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.object.equals?view=net-8.0

Так я и хочу написать, поэтому сюда и обратился
if (achivement.Equals(data.achivement[i]))
{
data.achivement.Remove(achivement);
}
else
{
data.achivement.Add(achivement);
}

Выдает ошибку, что индекс выходит из цикла

Помогло это:
public void SaveData(ref Data data){ 
    data.money = this.money;
    data.score = this.score;
    SerializableAchivementClass achivements = new SerializableAchivementClass();


    for (int i = 0; i < objects.Length; i++)
    {

        string id = objects[i].id;
        string content = objects[i].content;
        string nameAchivement = objects[i].nameAchivement;
        float requirement = objects[i].requirement;
        float reward = objects[i].reward;
        bool alreadyTaked = objects[i].alreadyTaken;
        AchivementClass achivement = new AchivementClass(id, nameAchivement, content, requirement, reward, alreadyTaked);
        achivements.Add(achivement);
        
    }

    if (achivements != data.achivement)
    {
        data.achivement = achivements;
    }
    else
    {
        data.achivement.Clear();
        data.achivement = achivements;
    }
}

